# Movie where memories could be shaped into real-world entities

Tags: story-identification, movie

As a child I co-watched a science fiction movie with my parents. It must have been almost 20 years ago. Unfortunately my memories are very vague and I can't recall the name. I didn't even completely understand what was going on as I was a child... The story is roughly as follows:

- The main protagonist of the movie was hijacked by a man when he was a child, together with his sister. I think he and/or his sister were abused, and he lost his sister.
- As an adult he is working with some science-fiction sort of technology which can make live 3D models of what he has in his mind. In the movie it appears as a mesh-ish screen that starts to form pictures which become 3D and awake to life.
- The protagonist tries to find the man who killed his sister using this technology. It happens to him that the man comes out of the screen and hunts him. One day the man appears within his own car all of a sudden and tries to choke him (although there is no mesh screen in the car).
- The protagonist eventually manages to identify the "record" of the culprit in some sort of public system and purges it. By that his culprit loses his identity and cannot even use the credit card anymore.

Comment: Reading your info it made me think of tarot by Piers Anthony and I think that is blocking my recollection lol maybe I will get further inspiration.  Was the movie new at the time?

Comment: @Dreamwalker - hm, reading a bit upon that book it seems very far from what I was trying to describe...

Comment: The world of tarot allows people to think of things and they manifest themselves in the world.  As I said it just makes me think of that not that it is related.  I am still having no luck on this I am sure I have seen it as well though :(

Comment: @Dreamwalker - got it.

Comment: Did you find the movie? If so, what's its name? You made me want to see it. :)

Comment: The moment I read your title, I immediately thought... _The Stay-Puft Marshmallow Man!_

Comment: @user35594: I guess I need some help to connect my question with your response :-) but I can tell that it is not what I was looking for.

Comment: @chiccodoro - Sorry, was a lame reference to Ghostbusters :)

Comment: A technology that lets you create serial killers just by speculating about their existence? I can't see that going wrong *at all...*

Answer (score 2):

I might be completely off, but this reminds me of Virtuosity (1995): http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114857/

Comment: From the description I tend to say, no. Although it includes simulation, virtual reality, and somebody coming into the real world. In the movie I am referring to the virtual/real criminalist is hunting only the main protagonist. Also, he is not a model of hundreds of serial killers, but a reconstruction of the memory of the main protagonist.